# How to subtract datetimes based on transition events in another column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, date, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe:

```
id      band        event_date  
1       LT          2005-09-05  
1       LP          2007-09-01  
1       P           2009-09-01  
1       LP          2010-08-02  
1       S           2011-07-01  
1       S           2016-07-11
```

I want to subtract the rows when there is a transition from LT to LP and LP to S and store it in days in two different columns. If there are similar band values then we need to take the first one and ignore the second one. Wherever there is no match return a blank or a dash(-)

**Expected Output**

```
    id      band        event_date    LT->LP    LT->S
    1       LT          2005-09-05    -         -
    1       LP          2007-09-01    726       -
    1       P           2009-09-01    -         -
    1       LP          2010-08-02    -         -
    1       S           2011-07-01    -         2125
    1       S           2016-07-11    -         -
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Option 1

- This is a partial solution, which calculates days when the transition is the next event, based on shifting by 1.

  - Perhaps this will give you, or someone else, an idea.
- This can be done by making a `Boolean` mask for each transition type, using `.shift()`.
- In regards to *Wherever there is no match return a blank or a dash(-)*, the blanks will be `NaN` because the rows will be `Float` type, or use `.fillna(0).astype(int)`, but numeric column may not contain `str` type.

```py
import pandas as pd

# test dataframe
data = {'id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 'band': ['LT', 'LP', 'P', 'LP', 'S', 'S'], 'event_date': ['2005-09-05', '2007-09-01', '2009-09-01', '2010-08-02', '2011-07-01', '2016-07-11']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# the event_date column must be a datetime dtype
df.event_date = pd.to_datetime(df.event_date)

# create the masks
mask1 = (df.band == 'LP') & (df.band.shift(1) == 'LT')
mask2 = (df.band == 'S') & (df.band.shift(1) == 'LP')

# create the two columns
df['LT → LP'] = (df.event_date - df.event_date.shift(1))[mask1].dt.days
df['LP → S'] =  (df.event_date - df.event_date.shift(1))[mask2].dt.days

# replace NanN with 0
df[['LT → LP', 'LP → S']] = df[['LT → LP', 'LP → S']].fillna(0).astype(int)

# display(df)
   id band event_date  LT → LP  LP → S
0   1   LT 2005-09-05        0       0
1   1   LP 2007-09-01      726       0
2   1    P 2009-09-01        0       0
3   1   LP 2010-08-02        0       0
4   1    S 2011-07-01        0     333
5   1    S 2016-07-11        0       0
```

### Option 2

- Given, *when there is a transition from LT to LP and LP to S*, however the expected result shows LT to S.

```py
import pandas as pd

# test dataframe
data = {'id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 'band': ['LT', 'LP', 'P', 'LP', 'S', 'S'], 'event_date': ['2005-09-05', '2007-09-01', '2009-09-01', '2010-08-02', '2011-07-01', '2016-07-11']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# the event_date column must be a datetime dtype
df.event_date = pd.to_datetime(df.event_date)

# filter the dataframe to only include the desired bands
filtered = df[df.band.isin(['LT', 'LP', 'S'])].copy()

# remove consecutive occurrences of a band
filtered = filtered.loc[filtered.band.shift(1) != filtered.band].copy()

# create the masks
mask1 = (filtered.band == 'LP') & (filtered.band.shift(1) == 'LT')
mask2 = (filtered.band == 'S') & (filtered.band.shift(1) == 'LP')

# create the columns in df
df['LT → LP'] = (filtered.event_date - filtered.event_date.shift(1))[mask1].dt.days
df['LP → S'] = (filtered.event_date - filtered.event_date.shift(1))[mask2].dt.days

# display(df)
   id band event_date  LT → LP  LP → S
0   1   LT 2005-09-05      NaN     NaN
1   1   LP 2007-09-01    726.0     NaN
2   1    P 2009-09-01      NaN     NaN
3   1   LP 2010-08-02      NaN     NaN
4   1    S 2011-07-01      NaN  1399.0
5   1    S 2016-07-11      NaN     NaN
```

### Option 3

- Create separate dataframes for the different event types

```py
# test dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 'band': ['LT', 'LP', 'P', 'LP', 'S', 'S'], 'event_date': [pd.Timestamp('2005-09-05 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2007-09-01 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2009-09-01 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2010-08-02 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2011-07-01 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2016-07-11 00:00:00')]})

# filter and create different dataframes for the different transitions
lt_lp = df[df.band.isin(['LT', 'LP'])].copy()
lt_s = df[df.band.isin(['LT', 'S'])].copy()

# remove consecutive occurrences of a band
lt_lp = lt_lp.loc[lt_lp.band.shift(1) != lt_lp.band].copy()
lt_s = lt_s.loc[lt_s.band.shift(1) != lt_s.band].copy()

# create a Boolean mask 
mask1 = (lt_lp.band == 'LP') & (lt_lp.band.shift(1) == 'LT')
mask2 = (lt_s.band == 'S') & (lt_s.band.shift(1) == 'LT')

# create the columns in the dataframe df
df['LT → LP'] = (lt_lp.event_date - lt_lp.event_date.shift(1))[mask1].dt.days
df['LT → S'] = (lt_s.event_date - lt_s.event_date.shift(1))[mask2].dt.days

# display(df)
   id band event_date  LT → LP  LT → S
0   1   LT 2005-09-05      NaN     NaN
1   1   LP 2007-09-01    726.0     NaN
2   1    P 2009-09-01      NaN     NaN
3   1   LP 2010-08-02      NaN     NaN
4   1    S 2011-07-01      NaN  2125.0
5   1    S 2016-07-11      NaN     NaN
```

Comment: I am really sorry that I could not come back to this earlier because of some issues. It's working fine! thank you so much!

Comment: @Django0602 You're welcome. Glad it works. I wasn't sure if there would be corner cases in the larger data set.